# how to update COSDictionary?

Tags: pdfbox

I'm creating  dictionary in the catalog.

```
PDDocumentCatalog catalog = template.getDocumentCatalog();
COSDictionary dssDictionary=new COSDictionary();
dssDictionary.setItem(COSName.getPDFName("Certs"), cosCerts);;
catalogDictionary.setNeedToBeUpdate(true);      
catalogDictionary.setItem(COSName.getPDFName("DSS"), dssDictionary);
```

**Ok. Everything works!**

**QUESTION 1)**
Now, Imagine that I need to update my dictionary.

I can get this dictionary like this:

```
COSBase dssCosBase = catalogDictionary.getDictionaryObject(COSName.getPDFName("DSS"));
```

Ok, It conataint my certificates. But how can I add another certificates here? It does any method for that.

**QUESTION 2)**
I can get COSBase object but how can I get COSDictionary object?

Comment: **Q2** *I can get COSBase object but how can I get COSDictionary object?* - check with `instanceof` and cast. **Q1** *But how can I add another certificates here?* - after casting (see answer to Q2) you can get the contained **Certs** dictionary, and after casting again... etc.

Comment: it works. write your question as an answer and I will check it as an answered :)

Comment: thank you very much.
COSDictionary dssDictionary =  (COSDictionary) catalogDictionary.getDictionaryObject(COSName.getPDFName("DSS"));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*To make my comment an answer...*

I answer the questions last to first:

> **Question 2)** I can get `COSBase` object but how can I get `COSDictionary` object?

Simply check whether the `COSBase` you have got, also is an instance of `COSDictionary` using `instanceof`. If it is, cast to `COSDictionary`.

> **Question 1)** But how can I add another certificates here?

After casting (see above) you can get the contained **Certs** dictionary, and after casting that again, you can work in that dictionary, e.g. adding another certificate.

In reaction to the comment, you found the following to work as you desired:

```
COSDictionary dssDictionary = (COSDictionary) catalogDictionary.getDictionaryObject(COSName.getPDFName("DSS"));
```

While this certainly will work for valid PAdES part 4 / PDF version 2 document security stores, you in general should be aware that there are broken documents for which **DSS** in the catalog is of a different type. Thus, I would always check with `instanceof` first.